Conditional expected value $ E[X|Y] $ is a function of $Y$
I would like to show or see a proof that the conditional expected value $ E[X|Y] $ is a function of $Y$ for arbitrary random variables $X,Y$ (especially not discrete or continuous).
I think for discrete random variables this is easy to see however I cannot seem to wrap my head around the general case.
I have read that the Doob-Dynkin lemma should do the trick however I do not see how.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

What is your starting point definition of $E[X|Y]$?

We have only defined it for discrete random variables in lecture so far as $ E[X|Y] = \sum_{y} E[X|Y=y] 1_{Y=y} $

This has been answered many times.

For the general definition I would've used $E[X|Y] = E[X|\sigma (Y)]$. Where $ \sigma (Y) $ is the sigma algebra generated by $Y$. For sigma algebras we defined $Z = E[X|\sigma (Y)]$ as a function that is $ \sigma (Y)$ measurable and $E[Z 1_G] = E[X 1_G]$ for all $ G \in \sigma (Y)$

So the general measure theory version of your question is "Why is a function that is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable a (measurable) function of $Y$?" The non-measure theory version of your question may just want to define $E[X|Y]$ by $g(Y)$ where $g(y)=E[X|Y=y]$.

Oh I see why the Doob-Dynkin lemma solves the problem. Thanks @Michael ! Since the random variable is $ \sigma (Y)$ measurable it has to be a function of $Y$. Am I correct?

Yes, that is correct.
